# Can I apply for a Schengen visa at a different consulate if no appointment dates are available?

Tags: schengen, germany, spain, netherlands, schengen-visas

I am planning to travel to visit my friends in Amsterdam on April 2nd week ( I just got a holiday confirmed ) and also go to Munich and Barcelona for 10 days. I would be in Amsterdam for 6 days, 2 days in Barcelona and 2 days in Munich. There are no appointment dates available for either the Spanish consulate or the Netherlands consulate at San Fransisco until mid May. Can I apply the Schengan visa at the German consulate? Any other option which might enable me to go in mid April? Any ideas/suggestions are welcome. I can slightly modify my travel plans. I am an Indian citizen living in USA on a H1B visa.

Comment: With your longest period of stay being in Amsterdam, the Dutch consulate is competent for your visa application. The Spanish or German consulate will refuse to process your visa application unless you lie about your travel plans and if it is uncovered that you lie about your travel plans, your visa or entry is likely to be refused. If you want to apply at the German consulate, you must modify your travel plans, so that you spend the most time in Germany.

Comment: Change your plans to mostly stay in Germany and you can safely apply there.

Answer (score 4):

> **5. Where do I submit my visa application?**
>
> You must lodge the
>   application for a Schengen visa at the Consulate of the country that
>   you intend to visit, or – if you intend to visit more than one
>   Schengen State, the Consulate of the country of your primary
>   destination (i.e. **main purpose of stay or longest stay**). If you intend
>   to visit several Schengen States and the stays will be of equal
>   length, you must apply at the Consulate of the country whose external
>   borders **you will cross first** when entering the Schengen area. As a
>   general rule, you must apply for a visa at the Consulate with
>   territorial competence for the country in which you legally reside.

https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf