# Deported from Estonia

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, deportation

I was deported from Estonia which is a Schengen country. I was carrying police clearance certificate for some business related activities as I planned a tour in Europe, but I did not mention about my police clearance certificate & business related work which is very uncertain, in the cover letter. Previously I have also done the same thing when I had traveled to France year 2014, I had a 3 months multiple entry tourist visa. No problems happened. Because everyone knows there is no distinction between a Schengen tourist visa & a Schengen business visa as long as they are both for the short term stay only(type c). So, with the existing tourist visa I can attend business related activities(market serve/ meeting / commercial purchase).

In keeping above fact in mind , I want to apply for Schengen visa again:

What would be the easiest Schengen country?

Comment: Please drop questions 2 and 3. This is not a letter-writing service.

Comment: When you say were "deported", do you mean you were actually hauled before a judge, convicted of some crime, and sentenced to be thrown out of the country? Or merely that you arrived at the border and was not allowed to enter?

Comment: It is true that there is no different type of visa for tourist and business activities, but it is also true that claiming to be a tourist when you intend to attend business meetings is contrary to the Schengen codes. I offer this only as an example of a possible reason for your deportation, because you haven't actually told us the reason cited by the authorities. Without knowing that reason, we cannot do much to help you. For example, we do not know whether Estonia entered a ban in the Schengen Information System; if so, the answer is that all countries will refuse you while the ban lasts.

Comment: @phoog a refusal of entry is not necessary a ban.

Comment: @greatone precisely. That's why I said "we do not know whether" there is a ban.  When someone is refused entry or deported or removed (whichever actually happened), they are given documents that explain the consequences; these should disclose whether there was a ban. Without knowing these details, it's impossible to give a helpful answer to the question, and the asker of the question has not added them, so I am voting to close it as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

The Schengen rules are [relatively clear](https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf), apply to the country which is your main destination (or the first visit in the case of multi-entry visas). This could be either the country you will visit longest or the one in which the primary purpose of the visit occurs. Part of the intention of the unified visa policy is to ensure there is no "easiest country" and prevent the kind of "visa shopping" you propose. See for example [this similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91698/can-i-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-at-a-consulate-of-a-country-i-dont-really-inten).

Comment: Actually there is a lot of anecdotal evidence that some countries issue visas more frequently than others. From my own experience applying for Schengen visas over the past thirteen years, Germany has been the toughest. Indeed I routinely alter my itinerary when applying so I apply through France or Spain. In theory they should all be similar however in practice it is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Short stay visa statistics for 2017 are available here https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/2017-consulates-schengen-visa-stats.xlsx Five countries are listed as having refusal rates of around 1%, including Greece and Finland. Knowing this data won’t help you if you were banned and your details entered into SIS, of course.

Comment: Regardless of whether there's a ban, the prior visa should have been revoked or annulled, and that would be listed in the VIS.  I suspect that the effect of that listing would be different in different countries, so the statistics may be less useful in this case than they would be in the general case.