# Schengen visa approved by French embassy, verbally asking to not enter Norway

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, france, norway

A friend of mine 'Yy' applied for a business visa to enter Norway. They were rejected. They appealed with the Norwegian embassy asking to change to a tourist visa to visit family. The appeal takes 3 weeks which is past their travel date. So, Yy changed their plans a bit and decided to visit France and Norway and applied for a Schengen visa to the French embassy because they have 3 days of processing time. Yy got a Schengen visa from the French Embassy. In addition, they also got a phone call from a 'French officer' asking to promise them on the phone that they will not visit Norway. Yy was surprised at that sudden question but said okay. Yy is confused that there is no place mentioned on the visa about this restriction (that they cannot enter Norway). Yy even called the Norwegian Embassy who told them on the phone that they can travel to Norway but they did not give it in writing. Yy has not received a reply on their appeal to the Norway embassy yet.

Question is: 
Can Yy travel to Norway via France to meet family? Yy plans to spend some days in France, meet family in Norway, head back to France and head home.

Comment: Did 'Yy' state in their application for the French visa that they intended to visit Norway as part of the trip? Also how long does he/she plan to spend in each country?

Comment: No doubt the answer partially depends on which country issued Yy's passport.  But given the first sentence, I think he/she had better be prepared to persuade a skeptical Norwegian that he/she does NOT intend to do business.  Or have someone at home watch the mail for the response to the appeal.

Comment: This sounds like it has a hint of visa shopping. I’d be pretty wary of trying to enter Norway on the basis you’ve described, but then I’m risk-averse.

Comment: @DJClayworth. Yy did not mention in their application for the French visa that they intended to visit Norway. They plan on spending 13 days in Norway and 7 days in France.

Comment: So "your friend" lied in their visa application and then lied again when the consulate called again to confirm the lie? I think I know who they have to blame whem this inevitably blows up in their face.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91698/can-i-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-at-a-consulate-of-a-country-i-dont-really-inten

Comment: The French call-back may have occurred because the French consular staff belatedly discovered they should not have issued the visa, and further suggests that both Norway and France now have the information from both visa applications. This does look like visa shopping, and I think entry into the Schengen Area may well be refused.

Comment: @David if the French consulate discovered evidence of fraud or other improper behavior, why didn't they just cancel or annul the visa?

Comment: My guess is that they don't at this stage, have proof that Yy really intends to visit Norway, and so they are giving him the benefit of the doubt for now. That will be withdrawn immediately they find out he has actually gone to Norway.

Comment: @phoog I don't know, and wondered that myself. Perhaps French consular staff only has a suspicion at this point, and DJClayworth's comment is on the right track.

Comment: An edit is not the proper way to delete a question (or request that it be deleted).

Comment: Please do not delete your questions. Self-destruction of content is not allowed on SE.

Answer (score 6):

It is a requirement of the Schengen visa that [you apply to the country that is your main destination](https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf). Your friend has already broken the rules by applying to France when he wants to visit Norway. You are also required to state your travel plans in the application, which your friend did not do. French authorities are already aware of your friend's desire to visit Norway, which is why they called him, to establish beyond doubt that he did not intend to visit Norway, and your friend lied to them a second time on the phone.

Can your friend legally use this visa to travel to Norway? **No absolutely they can not**. Doing so would mean that they had broken several rules and lied to immigration officials, both in the application and in person. The normal punishment for such violations is a long ban from entering the Schengen area. Immigration authorities are obviously aware of the situation and are in a position to make checks, such as monitoring internal flights.

Your friend's best option is to either visit France (and only France) as he requested, or to abandon his travel plans.

Comment: One might also wonder if the friend can expect a) another call from the French Embassy to say the visa has been cancelled; and b) an appeal refusal from Norway. Presumably the friend was unaware of how visa data is collected by Schengen authorities https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system_en

Comment: It seems that the applicant already lied, regardless of whether he in the end goes to Norway or not.  But by avoiding travel to Norway it might be possible to get through this without untoward consequences.